# how to generate output json file with i18next with CLI?

Tags: i18next

I am new to i18next parser. I followed https://github.com/i18next/i18next-parser instruction with CLI.
By running i18next 'app/**/*.{js,hbs}' 'lib/***/.{js,hbs}' [-oc] it parse all my JS files from app directory, but It never generate any json file.
I have output: 'locales/$LOCALE/$NAMESPACE.json' on my i18next-parser.config.js file.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the `output` argument.

```
i18next 'app/**/*.{js,hbs}' 'lib/**/*.{js,hbs}' -o=locales/$LOCALE/$NAMESPACE.json
```